# How to crop multiple selection and save into separated images without Photoshop

Tags: software-recommendation, batch-processing, selections, crop

Take a look at this image:

[image: image example]

My question is how to crop multiple selections at once into separate images. I want to select each panel of the comic and export them as individual images and do multiple exports at once. Do you have any suggestion how can I do this? I don’t have any clue how to do this.

I’m looking for a free way to do this (not Photoshop or some other pricey software).

Comment: You can use almost any raster image editor, even online ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a (free) website that I use sometimes use called [imagesplitter.net](https://imagesplitter.net/), you just select 2 rows and 3 columns.

Here's the result:

[image][image][image][image][image][image]

(because it does *center* the lines, it did cut off a bit of the borders, but I think it's fine.

Comment: With all the command line/script type solutions one might expect to see as an answer, this one is elegantly simple.